# Extract number inside brackets using regular expression?

Tags: r, regex, string, dplyr, gsub

Suppose I have a data frame like this one:

```
library(tidyverse)
index <- 1:1000
df1 <- data.frame(index = glue::glue('index[{index}]'),
                  X = rnorm(1000))
```

I want to `mutate` index so it is a numeric variable with the number inside the brackets. I can do that with this code:

```
df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(index = gsub(pattern = 'index[', replacement = '', x = index, fixed = T),
                      index = gsub(pattern = ']', replacement = '', x = index, fixed = T),
                      index = as.numeric(index))
```

I'm sure there is a better way of doing this with regular expressions. Ideally, I would like something that is agnostic to the text before `[`.

Comment: Can you guarantee that the only numbers are inside the brackets? Or do you need to potentially ignore numbers in the text before `[`. (As a side-note, it might take fewer code characters to use regex, but simple replacement with `fixed = TRUE` will probably be more computationally efficient.)

Comment: yes, only number will be inside the brackets

Comment: I'd suggest [looking through any of these questions about extracting a number from a string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+extract+number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
> df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(index = as.numeric(gsub("index\\[(\\d+)\\]", "\\1", index)))
> df2 %>% head
  index          X
1     1  1.1991921
2     2  0.5474659
3     3 -0.8437927
4     4 -1.8488537
5     5 -0.4673391
6     6 -1.1255241
```

Comment: is there a way to make this agnostic of the text using no standard evaluation? For example, if instead of `index` i have `SomeName`